# can you tell me the way of finding the location of any post of some other user in facebook?

Tags: windows

can you tell me the way of finding the location of any post of some other user in facebook???

Comment: can you share what you have tried, anything

Answer (score 0):

Go to there personal account. there you will get all there Posts